# Selenium End to End testing w/ different language bindings

Tags: testing, selenium, automated-tests

Here's the problem:

We have a healthy infrastructure of projects that contain selenium page objects and methods for each part of our site. However, each selenium project is written using the language its parent component is developed in. So for example, team A creates component A using  node.js and thus their selenium objects are written in js, while team B creates component B in .NET, and their selenium page objects in C#.

How can we write complete end-to-end selenium tests of our site with different parts using different languages for their selenium bindings? We of course want to maintain a separation of concerns, so team A doesn't need to concern themselves with the selenium details of team B. Should we be approaching this differently?

Answer (score 2):

Why not to agree on usage of one common language for test automation? It will solve consistency problem. All utils/libraries can be shared across the different teams, prevent from reinventing the same wheel.

Comment: I think there are definite benefits of having tests in the same language as the projects they are testing, no?

Comment: Yes, definetlly and it's already proved by experience. Especially when projects grow and new started.